# Is it possible to shift column data downwards in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql

I want to use a table like this:

```
+------+------------+-----------+
|  id  | col1       | col2      |     
+------+------------+-----------+
|  1   | abc        | mno       |
+------+------------+-----------+
|  2   | def        | pqr       |
+------+------------+-----------+
|  3   | ghi        | stu       |
+------+------------+-----------+
```

Is there a way to add a new row and shift a column downwards? Table should look like this...

```
+------+------------+-----------+
|  id  | col1       | col2      | 
+------+------------+-----------+
|  1   | abc        |           |
+------+------------+-----------+
|  2   | def        | mno       |
+------+------------+-----------+
|  3   | ghi        | pqr       |
+------+------------+-----------+
|  4   | jkl        | stu       |
+------+------------+-----------+
```

New row inserted with cell value for [row4, col1] = 'jkl', but i want to shift col2 data downwards, so [row1, col2] now becomes null.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Thank you RADAR & 2unco; had a play and you can also shift multiple columns within the same statement...

```
UPDATE mytable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t2 ON T1.id=T2.id + 1
SET t1.col2 = t2.col2, t1.col3 = t2.col3;
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But it begs for a design change.. after the INSERT (when "jkl"/"" are in a record) an UPDATE can self-join on itself and update with the value from the preceding ID-identified row.

Comment: How do we deal with the fact that we have to update the rows in reverse? i.e. if we update id 1 first (and set it to null) then id 2 and 3 and 4 will all become null. We have to go explicitly go in reverse order. Or... will SQL do it "all at once"?

Comment: @2unco - not sure what you mean; I want to emulate the shift() and push() JavaScript array methods within a MySQL table, so I'm only ever inserting new rows; previous rows will never be updated.

Comment: @user2864740 Sounds like trigger, right? Can you demonstrate an example? I've got a similiar problem too.

Comment: Sorry @Data, that question was regarding user2864740's suggestion and RADAR's answer below. I'll ask there again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE with self join

SQL Fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4f6c/1

```
 UPDATE Table1 T1
 JOIN Table1 T2 
 on T1.id=T2.id+1
 SET T1.col2 =T2.col2 ;

 UPDATE Table1 set col2 =NULL
 Where id=1;
```

EDIT:
In single statement

```
  UPDATE Table1 T1
  LEFT JOIN Table1 T2 
  on T1.id=T2.id+1
  SET T1.col2 =T2.col2 ;
```

Comment: @RADAR - Fantastic, that worked great. A minor sub-question, is there anyway to amalgamate the updates into one query?

Comment: Yes left join should do it

Answer (score 2):

One UPDATE can do it:

```
UPDATE mytable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t2 ON T1.id=T2.id + 1
SET t1.col2 = t2.col2;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/299d1/1

I thought we needed to use COALESCE to cover the first row, but we're just setting it to null in that case anyway so it effectively doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the null insertion, it's cleaner without the second update, but RADAR beat you to it, so I marked his as answered.